# Elegant way to handle multiple api check if it's null

Tags: go, swagger

Just curious how to simplify this following code manually inserting into code generated by Swagger in elegant way?

```
// Check some interface handler is defined;
// tell to the developer it not implemented once it's false
if api.AccountsGetAccountsProviderHandler == nil {
    api.AccountsGetAccountsProviderHandler = accounts.GetAccountsProviderHandlerFunc(func(params accounts.GetAccountsProviderParams) middleware.Responder {
        return middleware.NotImplemented("operation accounts.GetAccountsProvider has not yet been implemented")
    })
}
if api.NetworkGetNetworkProviderRegionCidrallocationsHandler == nil {
    api.NetworkGetNetworkProviderRegionCidrallocationsHandler = network.GetNetworkProviderRegionCidrallocationsHandlerFunc(func(params network.GetNetworkProviderRegionCidrallocationsParams) middleware.Responder {
        return middleware.NotImplemented("operation network.GetNetworkProviderRegionCidrallocations has not yet been implemented")
    })
}
if api.PodGetPodTenantHandler == nil {
    api.PodGetPodTenantHandler = pod.GetPodTenantHandlerFunc(func(params pod.GetPodTenantParams) middleware.Responder {
        return middleware.NotImplemented("operation pod.GetPodTenant has not yet been implemented")
    })
}
....
// 5000 similar lines
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to manually edit generated code, if that's what you're planning to do. And honestly, i don't think that there's much to simplify. This code, although is verbose, but looks clean and very readable.

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin Actually above code snippet  is not generated by Swagger. I updated the question description.